# Receiving hidden status bar/entering a full screen activity event on a Service

Tags: android, overlay, android-view, android-windowmanager, android-fullscreen

I have a service that adds some views to the window manager (something like facebook's chat heads). This views stay on top of everything all the time, even when I'm on the camera app. 
Is it possible to know when some activity (like the camera or a video player) is using full screen so I can hide my views?

Edit:

There's something called View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener but it requires API 11. My target is 9, but it looks like this is exactly what I need. Any alternative for API 9?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, if anyone is interested, I've solved my problem this way:
Added a transparent view to the window manager, with 1px width and match_parent height. Then added a global layout listener to this view, and everytime there's a change on the layout, I check the position of this view on screen. If it's Y is 0, then the status bar is not visible, so a full screen app must be running. This works even better than the native View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener because it seems there are some apps that somehow don't trigger that method (like the new yahoo weather).

Comment: Brilliant. This concept is based on the fact that the y coordinate of the view on screen (retrieved using view.getLocationOnScreen(locationArray)) will be automatically be reduced by the height of the status bar when any app enters full screen and hides the status bar (and vice versa). The change in y triggers the onLayoutChangeListener attached to the view due to the view being redrawn.

Comment: However, I just experienced a big problem - the getLocationOnScreen is not reliable when orientation changes. E.g. from a non-full screen app, launch a full-screen app that immediately changes orientation, and then press the home button after. The getLocationOnScreen fails to update correctly.

Comment: I found a method that does not rely on getLocationOnScreen! Mostly the same as your method, just that we check whether the height of the view (getHeight()) is equal the height of the window within the on layout listener; if it is equal, it implies that the app is in full screen. And onConfigurationChanged, we must remember to update the height of the window which is accessed by windowSize.y, using windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(windowSize); 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34215751/2669960