# Detect full screen in android from service

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service that creates system overlay window (always on top) like Facebook Messenger. I need to hide my window when any application is in full screen mode. However, I don't know how to detect it from the service.

This is how I add view in my service:

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
windowManager.addView(myView, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem a while ago (see: [Receiving hidden status bar/entering a full screen activity event on a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551135/receiving-hidden-status-bar-entering-a-full-screen-activity-event-on-a-service/19201933#19201933)).
I've solved it by adding a view to the window manager and control the y position of this view to check if the status bar is visible or not.