# Detect full screen from service Android

Tags: java, android

I need to detect the system ui visibility (full screen) from a service. I tried creating a custom view and adding `setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` but it never gets called.

```
public void setListener() {
    setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int i) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onSystemUiVisibilityChange =" + i);
        }
    });
}
```

I run `setListener` from my service's `onStartCommand`. What's wrong here? Or is there any other method to detect when the system ui is visible or not? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> ...from a service. I tried creating a custom view...

The custom `View` in your `Service` in not added to the View hierarchy that's drawn. That's why the method is not called. In an Activity you could do `mRootView.add(mCustomView)` and then check but that doesn't work from a `Service` since you don't have a reference to a visible layout.

For a (hacky) solution see this answer: [Receiving hidden status bar/entering a full screen activity event on a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551135/receiving-hidden-status-bar-entering-a-full-screen-activity-event-on-a-service/19201933#19201933)

If you have an `Activity` visible while the `Service` is running there are more options. You can bind the `Service` to an `Activity` and send updates from a`setOnSystemUiVisibility()` inside the `Activity` to the `Service`. 
See: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Or just send out a broadcast from the `Activity` when the UI state changes, which the `Service` listens for.

Comment: Thanks, the idea might work. But I'm having trouble implementing it so that when there is full screen I remove a custom view from WindowManager and then add it again.

Answer (score 1):

You can add one view (with full height) and use OnGlobalLayoutListener to listerner layout change, in onGlobalLayout check view.getHeight with max Y of screen.

```
if (mMaxY == helperWnd.getHeight()) {
    //full screen
} else {
//none full screen
}
```

Hope help you

Comment: Well this is what I'm actually doing.