# Hide navigation bar android 6.0 xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, hide

Goodmorning,
i'm trying to hide the navigation bar on my app android. i have device admin permission,i have created my kiosk app but i need to hide the navigation bar. in this moment i have no home button but i have back button.if i press on it the tablet say u can't exit app for device admin. to block the bar i use this

```
startlocktask()
```

i have tried devicePolicyManager.SetStatusBarDisabled()
but this hide status not home

i have this code for hide navigation  bar

```
 View decorView = Window.DecorView;
            var uiOptions = (int)decorView.SystemUiVisibility;
            var newUiOptions = (int)uiOptions;
            newUiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LowProfile;
            newUiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen;
            newUiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation;
            newUiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.Immersive;
            newUiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky;
            decorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)newUiOptions;
```

but when someone drag up the bottom bar this appear with only back button.i don't want that the user can see the navigation bar. can someone help me?

thanks 
regards

Answer (score 0):

This may help
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19201933/4172545

This is the answer from the link:

> Ok, if anyone is interested, I've solved my problem this way: Added a transparent view to the window manager, with 1px width and match_parent height. Then added a global layout listener to this view, and everytime there's a change on the layout, I check the position of this view on screen. If it's Y is 0, then the status bar is not visible, so a full screen app must be running. This works even better than the native View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener because it seems there are some apps that somehow don't trigger that method (like the new yahoo weather).

So with that you can have an event fire and when the Navigation bar is visible hide it, by calling your code again that you originally used to hide it.

Here is a little more concise way to write it :

```
 Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen, WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen); 

 Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility) 
                          (SystemUiFlags.LowProfile 
                          | SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen 
                          | SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation
                          | SystemUiFlags.Immersive
                          | SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky);
```

Comment: Hi Omar.thanks for the answer,i have tried to insert the code that u suggest to me on the on create method but the navigation bar still appear.what's wrong?thanks
andrea

Comment: I added an extra line to my code snippet. Also Xamarin has a weird bug if you have the `Use Shared Runtime` option enabled in Android Options sometimes the app doesn't show your latest code changes. I always disable it. Just make sure after you disable it to uninstall the app from the device you are testing on and re-deploy it.

Comment: HI Omar i will try this tomorrow but i'm very sure that i have already do that.i insert the code that you said to me under oncreate method(Window.setflag....)is it enough?thanks

Comment: Update:Hi omar i tried the code that u suggest to me but it doens't work,i tried to remove shared runtime but it doesn't work.Can you help me?thanks

Comment: Let me make sure I understand what you have. Is your problem that are not able to hide the navigation bar or that you can't keep it hidden. The code snippet I posted will only initially hide the nav bar not handle hiding it if a user makes it visible.

Comment: HI Omar,With my code or your code i can hide the bar.with my code i can make the kiosk mode(you can't exit up using home or back button.i need to keep hidden this bar.with the code that i have,when i slide to top the screen the bar appear.i need to keep hide this bar.my app is device admin if you need this information.thanks Andrea.